# Is there an equivalent to "mvn package" in npm?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to set up a CI/CD pipeline for a react application.
It should cover common stages such as *build*, *test*, *package*..
For a maven project, I would use `mvn compile`, `mvn test`, and `mvn package`.

Now, I am searching for the equivalent operations for `npm`.

As far as I understood there is `npm run build` for `mvn compile` and `npm test` for `mvn test`..
but so far, I could not find a command which resembles `mvn package`.
Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm run build` covers the "package" part in that it produces the compiled built assets, usually to the `/build` directory. This is what you would deploy.

Comment: I thought the `/build` is comparable to the `/target` directory which is created by `mvn compile`. I was looking for something which resembles the generation of a `.jar` file.. but from your response I am concluding that this doesn't exist and you usually run `serve` directly on the `/build` without having an "executable"?

Comment: That is correct - the form of a built react app is different from that of a `.jar`, however just like a `.jar` file, the build directory is the intended "executable" that is served to the end user.